# Excel VBA form lag

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an excel application that will open a userform when the user goes to a specific sheet. When the user clicks this sheet, the form appears. However, I don't want to user to be able to see what's in the sheet. I just want it to open without the lag or already be loaded in that sheet. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say you don't want the user to see the data on the sheet, do you mean the data from the form is on the sheet?  If so, why not make a sheet just to open the form?

Comment: If you don't want the user to see what's in the sheet, why require them to click that sheet to open the form? Can you use another mechanism to cause the form to open? A button on another sheet, perhaps?

Comment: Well I can't change the sheet's data because the cells are dependent in the rest of the application. Since people are somewhat used to going to this tab, it'll be nice for them to click this tab and go from there. Kind of a long story... Is there anyway to edit the behavior when a user clicks a tab at the bottom of the sheet? instead of opening the sheet, it opens the form?

Comment: Disable scrolling and put in a giant square shape to cover the data.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish, but it makes me wonder if it's a good design to implement in the first place.  If you make it so when you click on the sheet tab the form pops up, it gives the impression that Excel behaves a certain way when in fact you've hijacked the behavior entirely.  I would recommend thinking of a more natural way to show the form.  You could add a button in the Ribbon to show your form if you don't want to show the sheet it's connected to.  Or, if you have the time, it sounds like you need a stand-alone app instead of Excel.

Answer (score 2):

The following is as close as I can get to what you seek.

I have created a form with the default name of `UserForm1`.  I have included the code below in `ThisWorkbook`.

If the user clicks the "Sheet2" tab, the code loads `UserForm1`, maximises it and shows it. When the form is exited, the code switches to "Sheet3".

This does not exactly match your specification because you can see "Sheet2" for a fraction of a second before the form appears.  I have tried preloading the form.  I have tried switching off screen updating in the SheetDeactivate event routine and not switching it on again until I exit the SheetActivate Event routine.  But nothing I have tried prevents that brief flash.

Try this code and decide it is good enough.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

  If Sh.Name = "Sheet2" Then
    Load UserForm1
    With UserForm1
      .Width = Application.Width
      .Height = Application.Height
      .Show
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = False    ' Surpress SheetActivate event
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide all cells in the worksheet by first going:

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
MyUserForm.Show 'You can show modally here if you like
```

When you're ready to show the user the content again, you can use:

```
MyUserForm.Hide
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

The advantage here is that you don't lose the height and width of rows and columns during the process - they're restored to exactly their original formats.

Looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I like what you did, however when I try to implement in the worksheet_activate function I get an error: "Unable to set the Hidden property of the Range class"... any idea?

Comment: If you post your exact code (especially if it differs from the code above) and leave another comment to notify me, I'll test it on my machine and see what's going wrong. It should work if done exactly as above. Keep in mind that some actions can't be done during the execution of certain Excel events. This is likely something you want to do before the Worksheet_Activate event fires, or perhaps afterwards by dispatching it using: `Application.OnTime Now, "YourMethodName"`